# RegEx - Finding a string between pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to Regex and I'm struggling in finding a string inside a pattern.

I have this string:

```
{"linha":""},
{"linha":"              REDE GETNET"},
{"linha":"               SANTANDER"},
{"linha":""},
{"linha":"20/04/15 09:07:32 AUT:006299 DOC:000235"},
{"linha":"EC:000000000370484 TERM: T0385403    M"},
{"linha":"CV:010000024       CAIXA:00003333"},
{"linha":""},
{"linha":"CARTAO              ************2125"},
{"linha":""},
{"linha":"            CREDITO A VISTA"},
{"linha":"VALOR:        12,00"},
{"linha":""},
{"linha":"  ______________________________"},
{"linha":"         ASSINATURA"},
{"linha":""}, 
{"linha":""},
{"linha":"CUPOM: 00000000000000        MAC: 9235"},
{"linha":"NSU_CTF: 001899  LOJA: 0019  PDV: 897"},
{"linha":""},
{"linha":""}
```

I'd like to find the ocurrences between:

```
{"linha":
```

and

```
},
```

Getting only the string in double quotes after colon.

Until now my regex is:

```
(\{".*(linha).[:])
```

and it's getting only

```
{"linha":
```

Can someone help me? I intend doing it in javascript.

Comment: Are you sure that regular expressions are the best solution for this problem? You data appears to be JSON.

Comment: It is something like: `/\{\s*\"linha\"\s*\:\s*\"(.*)\"\}/g`? https://regex101.com/r/IjAJgB/1

Comment: Even if it wasn't JSON, a good'ol substring would be enough since the start and end parts seem to be constant.

Comment: To precise Hunter McMillen's hint: decode your string from JSON (examples: `json_decode` in PHP, `JSON.parse` in Javascript), then you can loop over the objects and extract `linha` properties

Comment: @Aaron Regex *could* be used, but it's not a good idea if you can avoid it. Use the right tool for the job. If this is JSON, then parse it as JSON. For example, what if one line is: `{"linha":"hello {\"world\"}!" },`, or `{"linha":null},` or `{"linha":123 },`? Regex could fail in all sorts of weird ways (as well as being harder to understand/update!), and there is almost certainly a better simple solution.

Comment: @TomLord I never said it couldn't be used. It's just not optimal, whether we're talking about performances or implementation cost/maintainability. I'm sure one could also train a neural network with a 100000-items dataset to obtain the same result, but why would they?

Comment: @Aaron A regex would be sensible as a quick and dirty solution for a limited (known) data set. But as a general solution that you should actually rely on in "important" code, using a JSON parser to parse JSON *is* optimal, both in terms of performance and cost/maintainability. Your comment about neural networks is just silly; I don't think it's at all unreasonable to suggest a JSON parser is the best way to parse JSON.

Comment: @TomLord I don't think it's unreasonable to suggest a JSON parser either, because it makes for a better maintainability / can be more easily generalized than the bare substring I was proposing. It's the regex solution I was qualifying of suboptimal (I don't see a single advantage over a substring with this data-set, and OP apparently needs help to craft one). The neural network was an exageration supporting the point that because you could didn't mean you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions in Javascript:

**Using Regex:**

```
var input_str = '{"linha":""},{"linha":"              REDE GETNET"},{"linha":"               SANTANDER"},{"linha":""},{"linha":"20/04/15 09:07:32 AUT:006299 DOC:000235"},{"linha":"EC:000000000370484 TERM: T0385403    M"},{"linha":"CV:010000024       CAIXA:00003333"},{"linha":""},{"linha":"CARTAO              ************2125"},{"linha":""},{"linha":"            CREDITO A VISTA"},{"linha":"VALOR:        12,00"},{"linha":""},{"linha":"  ______________________________"},{"linha":"         ASSINATURA"},{"linha":""}, {"linha":""},{"linha":"CUPOM: 00000000000000        MAC: 9235"},{"linha":"NSU_CTF: 001899  LOJA: 0019  PDV: 897"},{"linha":""},{"linha":""}'
var re = new RegExp('linha*\":(".*")', 'g'); 
var myArray;
while ((myArray = re.exec(input_str)) !== null) {
  var msg = 'Found ' + myArray[1];
  console.log(msg);
}
```

**Using JSON.parse**: Notice that i have added [] to wrap the string as JSON Array.

```
var input_str1 = '[{"linha":""},{"linha":"              REDE GETNET"},{"linha":"               SANTANDER"},{"linha":""},{"linha":"20/04/15 09:07:32 AUT:006299 DOC:000235"},{"linha":"EC:000000000370484 TERM: T0385403    M"},{"linha":"CV:010000024       CAIXA:00003333"},{"linha":""},{"linha":"CARTAO              ************2125"},{"linha":""},{"linha":"            CREDITO A VISTA"},{"linha":"VALOR:        12,00"},{"linha":""},{"linha":"  ______________________________"},{"linha":"         ASSINATURA"},{"linha":""}, {"linha":""},{"linha":"CUPOM: 00000000000000        MAC: 9235"},{"linha":"NSU_CTF: 001899  LOJA: 0019  PDV: 897"},{"linha":""},{"linha":""}]'
var parsed_json = JSON.parse(input_str1); 
console.log(parsed_json);
parsed_json.forEach(x => console.log(x.linha))
```

Comment: Upvoting because you showed also the amazing JSON way :)

Comment: But the regex you suggest does not work for me on the last case... https://regex101.com/r/SqgwBt/1/ (but it works for all OP cases)

Comment: yes, there was an issue (does not support quotes in the value) in the regex, i have edited the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the example is JSON, thus you should use JSON methods to get the data you want. BUT, if for any reason you are "forced" to use regular expression, than something like that may do the job:

```
/\{\s*\"linha\"\s*\:\s*\"(.*)\"\}/g
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/IjAJgB/1), and it is also robust with respect to (at least) `{"linha": " \" \" "}` and it also matches `{ "linha": ""}`. For sure there are some cases in which this regex will not work correctly (for example, it will not get numeric values, only strings).

Thus, again, you should really check out JSON. It is **amazing**! `:)`